# copying data to excel by criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have this vba code ,which is copying Physical memory data to one specific excel sheet,It is working fine,
But i want to make it generic,Whenever i will call this function i want to copy the data to different range

```
Sub PhysicalMemWMI()
Dim dTotalMemory          As Double
Dim dAvailable            As Double
Dim dFreeMem              As Double

sWQL = "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"
Set oWMISrvEx = GetObject("winmgmts:root/CIMV2")
Set oWMIObjSet = oWMISrvEx.ExecQuery(sWQL)

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Physical Memory")


    For Each oWMIObjEx In oWMIObjSet
        dTotalMemory = dTotalMemory + oWMIObjEx.TotalVisibleMemorySize
    Next
    dTotalMemory = dTotalMemory / 1024
    Set colItems = oWMISrvEx.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory", , 48)
    For Each objitem In colItems
        dFreeMem = dFreeMem + objitem.FreeAndZeroPageListBytes
        dAvailable = dAvailable + objitem.AvailableBytes
    Next objitem
    dFreeMem = dFreeMem / 1024 / 1024
   .Range("A2:B2").Value2 = Array(Format(((dTotalMemory * 1024 * 1024) - dAvailable) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, "#,##0.00 GB"), Format(dFreeMem, "#,##0 MB"))
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a parameter to your sub:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    PhysicalMemWMI ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
End Sub

Sub PhysicalMemWMI(destinationRange As Range)
    Dim dTotalMemory          As Double
    Dim dAvailable            As Double
    Dim dFreeMem              As Double

    sWQL = "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"
    Set oWMISrvEx = GetObject("winmgmts:root/CIMV2")
    Set oWMIObjSet = oWMISrvEx.ExecQuery(sWQL)

    For Each oWMIObjEx In oWMIObjSet
        dTotalMemory = dTotalMemory + oWMIObjEx.TotalVisibleMemorySize
    Next
    dTotalMemory = dTotalMemory / 1024
    Set colItems = oWMISrvEx.ExecQuery("Select * " & _
                         "from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory", , 48)
    For Each objitem In colItems
        dFreeMem = dFreeMem + objitem.FreeAndZeroPageListBytes
        dAvailable = dAvailable + objitem.AvailableBytes
    Next objitem
    dFreeMem = dFreeMem / 1024 / 1024
    destinationRange.Value2 = Array( _
                                Format( _
                                  ((dTotalMemory * 1024 * 1024) - dAvailable) _
                                      / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, _
                                      "#,##0.00 GB"), Format(dFreeMem, "#,##0 MB"))
End Sub
```

Note: Since you're only using the `destinationRange` once, there's no need for a `With` clause here.

(Untested code above, but it should work.)

Comment: Your code is only copying One value But I am copying both values to a specific sheet(called "Physical Memory" Ex: First time i want to Paste  @ (A1:B1) ...Then second time I want to paste the data @ (C1:D1).

Comment: Does it work if you call the sub with `PhysicalMemWMI ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B1")` ? My code is just an example, so you can add parameters however you like, e.g. define the number of values to copy, or the string format to use, or something similar. Hopefully the example is adaptable to your needs.